# Density of distance from origin in a general disc

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-measure, uniform-distribution

Consider the disc $|z-k| \leq r.$For the case of a unit disc ,the probability desnity of the distance from origin  of  a randomly and uniformly  chosen point in the disc is given by
\begin{equation}
f(u) = 
\begin{cases}
2u, & \text{if } \quad 0 \leq u \leq 1 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
However ,it is not  obvious  to me as to how we can find the same in case of the general disc mentioned .

Any help\hints\suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**PS**By origin i mean the origin of the coordinate system i.e. $(0,0)$ so I want the distribution of a randomly and uniformly chosen point in the ball from $(0,0)$ not from the center of the circle.

Comment: Can you make the question a little clearer? Waht is z, k and r. Are they real numbers? How is the randomly chosen point distributed and on what set? You PS is also a bit vague...

Comment: Sure,the equation is the complex equation of a circle with radius  r (real positive) and center k (complex).this circle and the interior of it is the set from which complex numbers have to b chosen randomly and uniformly

Comment: Perhaps a way to think about it that any disc is just a translation and a scaling of the unit disc. More precisely, the disc you wrote down with center $k$ and radius $r$ is just the image of the unit disc under the affine function $f: z\mapsto rz + k$, right? Do you see why the uniform measure on the "general" disc is just the push-forward of the unit disc under $f$?

Answer (score 2):

My apologies, this is sort of an answer in the making;it would have been too long for a comment Kindly somebody point out mistakes ,if any any and the possibility of proving the following assertion via a direct approach. I want to prove that for a fixed positive integer $l,$ the center of mass of  the $lth$ powers  of $m$ randomly and uniformly chosen complex numbers  from the disc $|z-c| \leq R,R>0  \quad \text{and}  \quad c \in \mathbf{C} $ approaches $c,$ the center of the disc.This is intuitively expected but i want to prove in  direct way.Here is what I have tried so far.

Let $ Z_1,Z_2, \cdots Z_m$ be randomly and uniformly chosen point in the disc $ |z-c| \leq R$ .My goal is to find the the bounds of $ \left |\frac{ \sum_1^m Z_k}{m} \right|$ and then take the limit as $m$ becomes arbitrarily large.We expect from symmetry conditions that  the  limit  approaches $|c|$ as $m \to \infty.$
Under the above conditions we see  we can write \begin{equation}
    Z_k=c+\sqrt{U_k}e^{\iota \theta_k}
\end{equation}
where $U_k $ is  circularly uniform over $(0,R)$ $\theta_k's$ are uniform  in the interval $(0,2 \pi)$ } and $k=1,2, \cdots m.$The square root is used because the probability density function (pdf) for the radius must be proportional to the area of the circle

We note
\begin{align*}
Z_k^l &= (c + r_k e^{i \theta_k})^l \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{l} \binom{l}{j} c^{l-j} r_k^j e^{i (j\theta_k)}, \quad k=1,2, \cdots, m
\end{align*}
Therfore,
\begin{equation*}
      \frac{\sum_1^m Z^k}{m}=\frac{1}{m} \sum_{k=1}^{m} \sum_{j=0}^{l} \binom{j}{l} c^{n-j}r_k^je^{\iota (j\theta_k)}
  \end{equation*}
Using triangular inequality and taking expectations :
\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{E}\left ( \left| \frac{\sum_1^m Z^k}{m}\right|\right)
      \leq \frac{1}{m}\sum_{k=1}^{m} \sum_{j=0}^{l} \binom{l}{j} |c|^{n-j} \mathbf{E}(r_k^j) \mathbf{E} (|e^{\iota (j\theta_k)}|)
\end{equation}
Now we note that
\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{E} (|e^{\iota (j\theta_k)}|)=1
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E}(r_k^j)= \frac{1}{R^2}\int_{0}^{R} 2x.x^{ \frac{j}{2}} dx = \frac{4}{R^2} \cdot \frac{R^{j+4}}{j+4}
\end{equation}
Hence ,
\begin{align*}
    \mathbf{E}\left ( \left| \frac{\sum_1^m Z^k}{m}\right|\right) & \leq \frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=0}^{l} \binom{l}{j} |c|^{n-j} \sum_{k=1}^{m} \mathbf{E}(r_k^j)\\
    & \leq 4 \sum_{j=0}^{l} \binom{l}{j} |c|^{n-j} \frac{R^{j+4}}{j+2}
    \end{align*}
If my calculations are correct ,the RHS of the last inequality must approach $|c|$ as $m \to \infty.$Unfortunately I do not know how I Can prove that from here.I would be highly obliged for any help/hints/suggestions.